# mysql : do case when with condition distinct

Tags: mysql, enums, distinct

I have two tables, and id is key to connect them. In one table has duplicated ids, with status column which is enum type. The other one has ids too but it is unique, and has columns like joined date. I have to know how many users joined by month and year, so I have to do group by year and month. This is the query so far I did.

```
SELECT year(member.joined) AS year, 
       month(member.joined) AS month, 
       count(DISTINCT member.id) AS count 
FROM member 
WHERE member.id NOT IN 
(SELECT internal.worker_id FROM internal) 
GROUP BY year(member.joined), month(member.joined);
```

and this gives me result like this.

```
year        month         count
1982         12            43           
1978         11             1
```

However, I also have to figure out count of kinds of users too, this is result I would like to get.

```
year        month         count     red   green  blue  
1982        12             43         1    40     2
1978        11             1          0     1     0
```

So I tried to edit query by adding name of enum column which have types like this.

```
count(DISTINCT member.id) AS count,
count(case c.`types` when 'red' then 1 else 0 end)as 'red',
count(case c.`types` when 'green' then 1 else 0 end)as 'green',
count(case c.`types` when 'blue' then 1 else 0 end)as 'blue'
```

and I got an error message that mysql syntax is not right. I tried this query whithout doing count(distint member.id) AS count, and it worked. However the result just shows everything without removing duplicates, so number of 'count' and others like red, green, blue does not match.
I wonder if it is possible to get result that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `(CASE WHEN c.types='red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` syntax?  It's the second version listed in [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case).  Also, the exact query and error message would be helpful -- what's table 'c', for example?  Is there a join here?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT year(member.joined) AS year, 
       month(member.joined) AS month, 
       count(DISTINCT member.id) AS count,
       sum(if(member.`types` like 'red', 1, 0)) as 'red',
       sum(if(member.`types` like 'green', 1, 0))as 'green',
       sum(if(member.types like 'blue', 1, 0))as 'blue'
FROM member 
GROUP BY year(member.joined), month(member.joined);
```

When using group by in this context it is better to use sum and if() clause